# Gradient descent - Arrow in plotted function

Tags: pgfplots, arrows, gradient

Im trying to explain gradient descent in a text I'm writing in LaTeX.

I have made a function that I would want an arrow from the top of the figure and downwards following the slope of the figure.
I can't seem to make it move to the right place and overlay the figure.

**Edit: The code now works, and shows a figure that could be used to help explain gradient descent - backpropagation**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{center}
    \caption{Gradient of graph}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        %q(\x) = 5*\x - 1;
        Z(\x,\y) = x^2+y^2; %+ q(\x);
    }]
    \begin{axis}
       [
       axis lines=center,
       enlargelimits,
       tick align=inside,
       domain=-1:1,
       samples=30, 
       minor tick num=7,
       ]

       \addplot3 [surf] {Z(x,y)};
       \draw [thick, -latex] (0,0) to [bend right] (0,3);
       \draw[dashed,line width=0.005\linewidth, ->] (axis cs:-1.1, 1.35, 1) -- (axis cs:0.0,-0.2,0.65);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your first coordinate given to the `\draw` command has three commas in it, but only two are allowed for 3D coordinates. Does that cause your troubles? To overdraw the surface put the `\draw` command after the `\addplot3` command. And to draw a dotted line add dotted to the `\draw` options.

Comment: HI, thank you for the answer. 
You did spot one error. I am used to using commas in floats from my Uni.
Anyways, I did not manage to do it right now. But I will give it a couple more tries. 
If I get to an answer I will post it :)

Comment: Because I don't know from where to where you exactly want to draw the arrow, here is a working example for a start: `\draw[->] (axis cs:0.8, 0.8, 2) -- (axis cs:0.2,0.2,0.2);`.

Comment: You are welcome. So is your question answered so we can close it?

Comment: yes, it can be closed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because   already solved with an update, as indicated in comments.